# Updating a variable inside another variable python

Tags: python

Whenever I update the variable the variable that has  the variable does not update with it. For example when the `gleft` variable is updated it does not update in `Game_Screen`. Can someone please help me fix this issue.

Ex: `gleft`is updated to `gleft = 'red arrow'`  but on the `Game_Screen` it is still the original `gleft = 'white arrow'`

```
from time import sleep
import random
import os
from datetime import datetime
clear = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')

title='\033[4;37;40m\033[1;37;40mGame\033[0;37;40m'

def Game():
    global perfect, cool, great,fail,point,Game_Screen,gleft
    point=random.choice([perfect,cool,great,fail])
    gleft='\033[1;37;40m⬅\033[0;37;40m'
    gright='\033[1;37;40m➡\033[0;37;40m'
    gup='\033[1;37;40m⬆\033[0;37;40m'
    gdown='\033[1;37;40m⬇\033[0;37;40m'
    Game_Screen=f'''┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                       {title}                        |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                   {gleft}  {gup}  {gright}   {gdown}                                |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 
'''
while True:
    Game()
    print(Game_Screen)
    gleft='\033[1;31;40m⬅\033[0;37;40m'
    print('Updated :',gleft)
    sleep(3)
    clear()
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that.

Comment: Well, you’re resetting `gleft` inside `Game`…

Comment: you should learn how to use classes

Comment: It worked but it is going to be a very long process I think I should learn how to use classes it might make things better.

Comment: Someone tell me how to close a question